# Weakness in Reduce and Solve and FindInstance

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

In 14.0 on Windows 10 I solve a trig equation
$$2 \cos ^{-1}(\sin (\pi  x))=\pi  \cos \left(\sin ^{-1}(x+1)\right) $$

by

```
Reduce[2 ArcCos[Sin[Pi *x]] == Pi *Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]], x, Reals]
```

> `False`
> Reduce::fexp: Warning: Reduce used FunctionExpand to transform the system. Since FunctionExpand transformation rules are only generically correct, the solution set might have been altered

The same issue with `Solve` and `FindInstance`. That result is not correct: for example, `x==-1` is a solution. Taking into account the function domain of the LHS minus the RHS, I succeed by

```
Reduce[2 ArcCos[Sin[Pi *x]] == Pi *Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]] && 
FunctionDomain[2 ArcCos[Sin[Pi *x]] - Pi *Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]],x], x, Reals]
```

> `x == -(9/5) || x == -1`

Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: Concerning numeric solutions, `NSolve[2 ArcCos[Sin[Pi *x]] == Pi *Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]], x, Reals]` reports `{}` and "NSolve::fexp: Warning: NSolve used FunctionExpand to transform the system. Since FunctionExpand transformation rules are only generically correct, the solution set might have been altered." and `NMinimize[(2  ArcCos[Sin[Pi*x]] - Pi*Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]])^2, x]` returns the input together with a warning "NMinimize::nrnum: The function value -19.6116-28.3921 I is not a real number at {x} = {0.934341}".

Comment: @The down-voter: What is incorrect in the question? To downvote without a  comment is not a good practice.

Comment: BTW, I don't see how to solve this equation by hand.

Comment: [CASE:5119902] is submitted by me: "Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support. I will pass this report along to the developers in charge of this functionality".

Comment: A bit disappointing that `Reduce[2  ArcCos[Sin[Pi*x]] == Pi*Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]] && 
  Pi*Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]] \[Element] Reals, x, Reals]` works and the original fails. I suppose everyone know, or should be made aware, that the methods available for problems over bounded domains are different and sometimes more robust. For instance, this seemingly trivial change yields the solution: `Reduce[2  ArcCos[Sin[Pi*x]] == Pi*Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]] && (-100 < x < 100 || Abs[x] >= 100), x, Reals]`

Comment: @Goofy: But `Reduce[2   ArcCos[Sin[Pi*x]] == 
   Pi*Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]] && (-1 < x < 1 || RealAbs[x] >= 1), x, Reals]` performs `False` and a warning.

Comment: @ user64944 An `Reduce[2  ArcCos[Sin[Pi*x]] == 
   Pi*Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]] && (Abs[x] < 100 || Abs[x] >= 100), x, Reals]` performs `False `and a warning.

Comment: @ user64944 And `Reduce[2  ArcCos[Sin[Pi*x]] == 
   Pi*Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]] && (RealAbs[x] < 100 || 
    RealAbs[x] >= 100), x, Reals]` performs `False `and a warning.

Comment: @ user64944 And `Reduce[2  ArcCos[Sin[Pi*x]] == 
   Pi*Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]] && (-100 < x < 17 || x >= 17), x, Reals]` performs `False `and a warning.

Comment: BTW, I must have misunderstood your question. I didn't think you were interested in finding more ways for it to return `False`. How many more do you want? I suspect there's an unlimited number.

Answer (score 11):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"];

eqn = 2  ArcCos[Sin[Pi*x]] == Pi*Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]];
```

Plot the equation

```
ContourPlot[eqn, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

From the plot, restrict the domain:

```
sol1 = Solve[{eqn, -2 < x < 0}, x, NegativeReals]

(* {{x -> -(9/5)}, {x -> -1}} *)

eqn /. sol1

(* {True, True} *)
```

Or,

```
sol2 = NSolve[{eqn, -2 < x < 0}, x] // Rationalize

(* {{x -> -(9/5)}, {x -> -1}} *)
```

Or,

```
sol3 = FindRoot[eqn, {x, #}] & /@ {-0.9, -1.7} // Rationalize

(* {{x -> -1}, {x -> -(9/5)}} *)
```

Or,

```
sol4 = FindInstance[{eqn, -2 < x < 0}, x, 2]

(* {{x -> -(9/5)}, {x -> -1}} *)
```

**EDIT:** Another graphical approach:

```
plt = Plot[Evaluate[List @@ eqn], {x, -3, 1},
  MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, Evaluate[Subtract @@ eqn]],
  Mesh -> {{0.}},
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Red],
  PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.375, .8}]]
```

[image]

```
sol5 = {x -> #} & /@ 
   Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plt // DiscretizeGraphics][[All, 1]] // 
  Rationalize[#, 10^-5] &

(* {{x -> -(9/5)}, {x -> -1}} *)
```

Comment: In fact , you find `FunctionDomain[2 ArcCos[Sin[Pi *x]] - Pi *Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]]` over the reals (which is exactly `x>=-2&&x<=0`), making use of a plot
 ("From the plot, restrict the domain"). This is my answer in other formulas. Because of this reason I can neither up vote nor accept it.

Comment: -1. I'd like to add that `Solve[{eqn, -2 < x < 0}, x]` produces "Solve::incs: Warning: Solve was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete. `{{x -> -(9/5)}, {x -> -1}}`". Your `NegativeReals` stands to disguise it.

Comment: Use `Solve[{eqn, -2 < x < 0}, x, Complexes]` As shown in the documentation, "Solve[expr && vars \[Element] Reals, vars, Complexes] solves for real values of variables, but function values are allowed to be complex." In this specific case a tighter constraint than `vars \[Element] Reals` is used.

Comment: `Solve[{eqn, -2 < x < 0}, x,Reals]`  works in the end, taking a dozen of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

When solving the equation under consideration, complex numbers appear (say, `ArcCos[2]`). To overcome that circumstance, we can rewrite the equation as `Re[]^2+Im[]^2  == 0`,then

```
FindInstance[Re[(2  ArcCos[Sin[Pi*x]] - Pi*Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]])]^2 + 
Im[(2  ArcCos[Sin[Pi*x]] - Pi*Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]])]^2 ==  0, x, Reals, 3]
```

> FindInstance::fwsol: Warning: FindInstance found only 2 instance(s), but it was not able to prove 3 instances do not exist.`{{x -> -1}, {x -> -(9/5)}}`

works,

Comment: `FindInstance[
 Re[(2  ArcCos[Sin[Pi*x]] - Pi*Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]])] == 0, x, Reals, 3]` performs `{{x -> 453/2}, {x -> 137/2}, {x -> -(695/2)}}`.

Answer (score 1):

These are all complex solutions. There might be more if we take `ArcSin` and `ArcCos` as multivalued functions.

```
sol = {9/5 - (2 I Sqrt[11])/5, 
   1/5 - (2 I)/5, -1, -3 - (2 I)/Sqrt[5], -(23/5) - (2 I Sqrt[19])/5, 
   9/5 + (2 I Sqrt[11])/5, 
   1/5 + (2 I)/5, -(9/5), -3 + (2 I)/Sqrt[5], -(23/5) + (
    2 I Sqrt[19])/5};

With[{x = a + I b}, 
 ContourPlot[{Re[2 ArcCos[Sin[Pi*x]] - Pi*Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]]] == 0, 
   Im[2 ArcCos[Sin[Pi*x]] - Pi*Cos[ArcSin[x + 1]]] == 0}, {a, -10, 
   10}, {b, -4, 4}, PlotPoints -> 100, Epilog -> Point@(ReIm /@ sol)]]
```

---

[image]